# some questions related to Google Wallet API

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-pay

I am new to **Google Wallet** API and I cant find answers to a bunch of questions so here they are:
1. can I use my *carrier's credit* (like in the **in-app purchases**) as a method of payment in **Google Wallet**?
2. Should the money be in dollars or could it be in any currency?
3. is it possible to link every purchase in the app with a different **Google Wallet**?
Thank you so much :)

Comment: Answer for your question2: Money in Google-Wallet can be in any currency. But while paying to the merchant depending on the payment gateway you implement currency conversion charges will be involved.